# How to put variables in awk?

Tags: scripting, ksh

I am experiencing a problem while running this code:

```bash
end=some variable

for var in 'cat /Desktop/list.txt'; do
    awk '/$var/,/$end/' text.txt
done
```

My question is: Can I use awk this way ? I think $var and $end causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your variable is outside awk.
So to pass a variable into awk you will have to use “-v var=$var -end=$end while calling awk“ option. Once done remove $ from awk text match as awk consider it as variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

i mean shell quoting is always prudent, but

1. `awk` *mostly* plays nice with variables coming in this way
2. not shell quoting usually isn't a good idea, but at times it still works
3. placing the new variables directly into `/../` type regex doesn't work :

> ```
>  echo "${TMPDIR}" | 
>
>  gawk -v __=$TMPDIR -I -d- -p- -be '{ print __ } /__/'
> ```

```
+ Op_newfile
+ Op_no_op
+ Op_after_beginfile
+ Op_get_record
+ Op_rule
+ Op_exec_count
+ Op_exec_count
+ Op_push
+ Op_K_print
```

**`/var/folders/79/fj0xctsj3y7d1w7lltrztdyw0000gn/T/`**

```
+ Op_no_op
+ Op_rule
+ Op_exec_count
+ Op_match_rec
+ Op_jmp_false
+ Op_no_op
+ Op_jmp
+ Op_get_record
+ Op_newfile
+ Op_no_op
+ Op_after_endfile
+ Op_newfile
+ Op_no_op
+ Op_atexit
+ Op_stop
    # gawk profile, created Fri Aug  5 00:47:19 2022

    # Rule(s)

     1  {
     1      print __
    }

     1  /__/ {
        print           <————— notice there's no corresponding
                               "1" to left of it, meaning regex no match
    }

ARGC: 1
ARGIND: 0
ARGV: array, 1 elements
.
.
.
TEXTDOMAIN: "messages"
__: "/var/folders/79/fj0xctsj3y7d1w7lltrztdyw0000gn/T/"
```

but something like this would work instead

—- (use `index()` if you're too lazy to escape any potential special characters within `"__"`):

> ```
>     1  ($_)~__, // { # 1
>     1     print
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `awk` parameters like this:

```
end="some variable"
for var in $(cat /Desktop/list.txt); do
    awk -v awkvar1="${var}" -v awkvar2="${end}" '/awkvar1/,/awkvar2/' text.txt
done
```

Once you know what you are doing, you can use the same variable names inside and outside `awk`, but it might become confusing,

```
end="some variable"
for var in $(cat /Desktop/list.txt); do
    awk -v var="${var}" -v end="${end}" '/var/,/end/' text.txt
done
```